# PHP combine multiple arrays into one single entity

Tags: php, arrays, json, function, output

array1 look like this

```
 $array1 = [{
        'id': 1,
            'name': 'John'
    }]
```

and here is array2 :

```
$array2 = [{
    'id': 1,
        'name': 'someone'
}, {
    'id': 1,
        'name': 'Rocky'
}, {
    'id': 1,
        'name': 'Samuel'
}]
```

I want something like this:

```
$array1combinedwitharray2 = [{
    'id': 1,
        'name': 'John'
}, {
    'id': 1,
        'name': 'someone'
}, {
    'id': 1,
        'name': 'Rocky'
}, {
    'id': 1,
        'name': 'Samuel'
}

]
```

I tried several time and the result was the array goes into another array.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Plz post valid php code first.

Comment: Is this php array? i think you post a json format data. Please post your array data in valid php format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like those are JSON data , so decode them using `json_decode()` and finally do an `array_merge()` with `json_encode()` as the wrapper.

#### The code..

```
$array1combinedwitharray2 = json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($array1,true),json_decode($array2,true)));
```

Comment: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Then just do `$array1combinedwitharray2 = array_merge($array1,$array2); echo json_encode($array1combinedwitharray2);` instead of the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the array_merge method  : 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

Those are JSON Objects first you need to convert them to array then merge them and then encode to JSON format.

```
$array1combinedwitharray2 = json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($array1,true),json_decode($array2,true)));
```